# Black text in generated image after install PHP-GD

Tags: pdf, jpeg, imagick, php-gd

I am using imagick to convert generated pdf to jpg/png and save it to server.
All works well but after install php-gd because of use png images in mpdf all text in generated jpg are black.

Here is my code when actually works without php-gd but without it PNG images arent show in document.

```
$mpdf->Output('temp/'.$nazev_pdf.'.pdf','F');
$pdf_file = 'temp/'.$nazev_pdf.'.pdf';
$savepath = 'temp/'.$nazev_pdf.'.jpg';
$img = new imagick();
$img->setResolution(576,576);
$img->readImage("{$pdf_file}[0]");
$img->resizeImage(2480,3508);
$img->setCompressionQuality(100);
$img->setImageFormat('jpg');
$img->writeImage($savepath);
```

[image]

I dont know how to fix it. Anybody know ?

EDIT:
I am check generated MPDF PDF and text is OK in PDF format. So text get wrong in imagick convertion.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. PDF is transparent so I set PNG and modify img convert.

```
$mpdf->Output('temp/'.$nazev_pdf.'.pdf','F');
$pdf_file = 'temp/'.$nazev_pdf.'.pdf';
$savepath = 'temp/'.$nazev_pdf.'.png';

$img = new imagick();
$img->setResolution(576,576);
$img->readImage("{$pdf_file}[0]");
$img->resizeImage(2480,3508);
$img->setCompressionQuality(100);
$img->setImageBackgroundColor('white');
$img->setImageCompose(\Imagick::COMPOSITE_ATOP);
$img->flattenImages();
$img->setImageFormat('png');
$img->writeImage($savepath);
```